# transistor voltage drop

Tags: voltage, transistors

I'm having an issue with a transistor.

I'm apply ~3.3v to the base, 4.7v to the collector, but only getting ~2.5v from the emitter. I need to be getting close to the full 4.7v I'm aware there is always some voltage drop across c/e, but 2.2 volts seems excessive. Have I missed something?

Comment: I suspect you're using an NPN Darlington and you've got a resistor connected between the emitter and GND.  Can you post a schematic?

Answer (score 8):

You need a high-side switch to get this to work, as in this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95623/using-npn-transistor-as-switch) 
[image]

Q3 shifts the 3.3V level to your 4.7V (rather than the 9V shown) and R2 supplies base current for Q2. R3 prevents leakage in Q3 from being amplified by Q2.

Pick R2 to give about 1/10 to 1/20 of the load current. R3 can be a few times larger than R2 and you can make R1 of similar value to R3.

Q2 should saturate when on and give you tens to hundreds of mV drop from the 4.7V rail depending on the transistor and the load current. If you substitute a logic-level p-channel MOSFET for Q2, you could make the drop even lower under favorable conditions. For example, a 5m\$\Omega\$ Rds(on) power MOSFET would have a drop of only 50\$\mu\$V at 10mA.

Comment: Hey @Sphero, I managed to get this working, but with the removal of R3 (And connecting wires ofc). How does this circuit work with R3 connected, because it seems that this would cause Q2 to be constantly saturated.

Answer (score 4):

The emitter voltage is limited by the base voltage since ~Vbe must be greater than ~0.6V to turn on the transistor. You've made an emitter follower, not a switch. If you want to switch the full voltage, use a PNP transistor instead.

Comment: I dont quite follow, what is Vbe? The difference between base and emitter voltages?

Comment: Yes - Vbe is the voltage between base and emitter.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Trying to drive an LED on 5V with a 3.3V to the base. Initially, I put the LED between Emitter and Ground and when I checked, it was providing only 2.8V. I changed the circuit to have the LED between VCC (5V) and the Collector and put Emitter to Ground and it works fine now.

Circuit is as follows (built using [circuitlab](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#)):
[image]